# python Import Error: no module named app

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

First, I created `__init__.py` in my `app` folder

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
from app import views
```

and then, I created `views.py` in the same app folder

```
from app import app

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return "Hello, World!
```

and lastly, I created `run.py` in a different folder

```
#!flask/bin/python
from app import app 
app.run()
```

so, my flask tree is like

```
/microblog
    /app
        /__init__.py
        /views.py
    /flask
    /tmp
        /run.py
```

But, when I try to run `run.py`, I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/shubham/Microblog/tmp/run.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app import app 
ImportError: No module named app
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/home/shubham/Microblog/tmp/run.py"]
[dir: /home/shubham/Microblog/tmp]
[path:      /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games]
```

Comment: Try moving `run.py` from `tmp` under `microblog`. I think it is just a `PYTHONPATH` issue; your run.py cannot find your app module.

Comment: Please don't tag your text editor. We don't care.

Comment: #llja I tried but it gives me a new error i.e. " AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'route' " now what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you don't have a clear understanding about the differences between imports, variable names, and packages. And how imports work.

When you're structuring a Python package, you'll typically have your toplevel folder with a `setup.py`, `README` and other assorted files in it, then your package folder. You might want something that looks like this:

```
├── microblog
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── server.py
│   └── views.py
├── README
├── MANIFEST.in
└── setup.py
```

If you *really* didn't want to put your URL handlers in the same place as your app, you've got it a little backwards though. You should do it like this:

## server.py

```
from flask import Flask
from . import views

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(views.microblog)


def run():
    app.run(debug=True)
```

## views.py

```
from flask import Blueprint

microblog = Blueprint('microblog', __name__)

@microblog.route('/')
@microblog.route('/index')
def index():
    return 'Hello, world!'
```

## setup.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='microblog',
    version='0.1.0',
    description='My microblog',
    author='Me',
    author_email='me@example.com',
    url='http://my.cool.example.com',
    packages=[
        'microblog',
    ],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'start-my-blog = microblog.server:run'
        ],
    },
    package_dir={'microblog': 'microblog'},
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=['flask',
    ],
    license="BSD",
    zip_safe=False,
    keywords='',
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 2 - Pre-Alpha',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License',
        'Natural Language :: English',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
    ],
)
```

Now you can create yourself a virtualenv, install your app, and then run it:

```
$ mkvirtualenv microblog
$ workon microblog
(microblog) $ python -m pip install -e .
# a bunch of install happens here, flask & what-not
$ start-my-blog
```

If you want to change the name of the command to run, you'll do that in your setup.py. Starting out with a structure like this will save you a lot of headaches down the road.